# Doesn't change fragment backstack size when I press back button in Actvity

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is my code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
try {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);          
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);            
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();            
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I am adding first fragment, my method `getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()` returns 0.

When I am adding second fragment `getBackStackEntryCount()` returns 1, but when I am pressing back button `getBackStackEntryCount()` still returns 1.

Why?

**UPD** -

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    updateToolbar(); // here I check backstackCount and update Toolbar
}
```

**UPD2** -

```
private void updateToolbar() {            
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()() > 0) {
        showBackButtonOnToolBar();
    } else {
        showProfileButtonOnToolBar();
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post your `onBackPressed` method?

Comment: Why are you using `commitAllowingStateLoss`?

Comment: @AlexKlimashevsky done

Comment: @MuratK. - I dont know why... I tried commitNow() but it's doesn"t work for me

Comment: What kind of change are you trying to make to the toolbar?  You might be able to accomplish it without counting stack entries.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to call `popBackStack()` from your `onBackPressed()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
    {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();           
    }
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Update:

add your line `updateToolbar();` below pop call inside if statement.

Comment: doesn't work for me. In super.onBackPressed() code like your

Comment: if (!mFragments.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

Answer (score 1):

Answer is similar to Sarthak's, however instead of calling:

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();           
}
else {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

call the instance of YOUR fragment manager i.e `fragmentManager`

like so:

```
if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
   fagmentManager.popBackStack();           
}
else {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

UPDATE:

Probably best to create a `FragmentManager` field, initialise it in the `onCreate` of your activity and then use that throughout all fragment transactions, adding to back stack and so on.